# simple construct like the following

Tags: c#, .net

Is there anything in the C# which like the following `<key, string, string>` which I can use key to access the second and third field quickly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you have indicated that you are not using .NET 4, you will have to define a class or struct to hold the two strings you are interested in:

```
class Foo
{
    public StringOne { get; set; }
    public StringTwo { get; set; }
}
```

Then use a `Dictionary<string, Foo>`, like so:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, Foo>();
dict["key"] = new Foo() {
    StringOne = "Hello",
    StringTwo = "World"
};
```

Don't forget to give the class and its properties some meaningful names.

Comment: KeyValuePair is not what you want; it is intended for use in dictionaries and other things that map keys to values.  Please see my updated answer, which will work with C# 3 and .NET 2.0/3.5.

Comment: looks like it is just pair<T,T>, any difference?

Comment: A meaningful pair class is the right way to go.  If the information is being stored together, it likely has some meaning as a pair that can be given an appropriate name.  If this is used in an internal data store for some class, you can also make it a private nested class to reduce 'class clutter'.

Comment: @user496949, the difference is in the naming, which describes a particular intention.  Classes that are convenient for some purpose, but whose names don't properly describe intention are often misleading to an engineer working to understand and maintain the code.

Comment: got it. Adopt the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not write this

```
class StringPair {
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
}

Dictionary<TKey, StringPair>
```

Comment: don't like additional class for this simple task

Comment: There isn't much else you can do. Sorry.

Comment: Tuple is really better. Unfortunately it is in 4.0 only

Comment: Its basically what I have here.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
class Table<TKey, TValues>
{
    Dictionary<TKey, int> lookup;
    List<TValues[]> array;

    public Table()
    {
        this.lookup = new Dictionary<TKey, int>();
        this.array = new List<TValues[]>();
    }
    public void Add(TKey key, params TValues[] values)
    {
        array.Add(values);
        lookup.Add(key, array.Count - 1);
    }

    public TValues[] this[TKey key]
    {
        get { return array[lookup[key]]; }
        set { array[lookup[key]] = value; }
    }
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Table<int, string> table = new Table<int, string>();
        table.Add(10001, "Joe", "Curly", "Mo");
        table.Add(10002, "Alpha", "Beta");
        table.Add(10101, "UX-300", "UX-201", "HX-100b", "UT-910");

        string[] parts = table[10101];
        // returns "UX-300", "UX-201", "HX-100b" and "UT-910".
    }
}
```